# How to allow public or private downloads of static files with PHP 5.4 Web Server?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, silex, php-5.4

I'm using Silex/Symfony 2 framework. Users may upload either private (`web/assets/uploads/*.*`) and public documents (`app/uploads/*.*`), uploaded file is moved to the right folder with a sanitized name, and a new record is created in the `upload` table.

```
+-app/
| +-.htaccess                 <-- Deny from all
| +-uploads/                  <-- private upload folder
|   +-private_upload.pdf      <-- private document
+-web/
  +-index.php                 <-- front controller
  +-assets/
  | +-img/
  | +-css/
  | +-js/
  | +-uploads/                <-- public upload folder
        +-public_document.pdf <-- public document
```

Assets like images and css uploads should be served as usual, i.e. a direct link to the filename:

```html
<img src="/web/assets/img/logo.png" />
```

### Apache configuration idea (production environment)

Files in **private or public upload folders** should be served using a controller for getting the sanitized name and checking permissions.

Right now all requests (for files that don't exist) passes through the front controller `index.php`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /web
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Requests for `app/*` are denied using `.htaccess` file. Is this correct and safe?

### PHP 5.4 Web Server issue (development environment)

In my `index.php` I've the following code:

```php
$filename = __DIR__.preg_replace('#(\?.*)$#', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server' && is_file($filename)) {
    return false;
}
```

If a request is for a filename and (the file actually exists) `index.php` returns `false`, allowing the PHP 5.4 Web Server to serve the file statically.

The problem is that those lines won't allow me to catch routes like `/files/private_document.pdf`, managed with my `FilesController` class:

```php
$controllers->get('/files/{file}', 'file_controller:serveAction')
    ->assert('file', '.*')
    ->bind('file_serve');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server') {
    if(is_file(__DIR__.preg_replace('#(\?.*)$#', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The solution for PHP 5.4 web server, along with starting the server itself with:

```
php -S localhost: 80 -t /path/to/web /path/to/web/index.php
```

This way, if `/css/style.css` exists it will be served statically, but `/files/dynamic.css` will pass through the front controller.

Comment: Thank you. I was banging my head and now I finally understand how it actually looks for files in a path before routing to the php server file.